# "best" way to get size of a list

Tags: django, python-3.x

My question is, if I have a list

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

if I want to know the number of elements in this list, is 
len(list) or list.count the better option?
or does .count only aplies to queries from model by object.filter(id = "HI").count?

hope I make myself clear.

Comment: `list.count` is for finding out how many entries in a list are of some specific value. You must pass that value when you call it. So `len` is the only way of the two to get the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Would a better title for your question be `“best” way to get size of a django queryset` ??

Comment: @PaulRooney No, i was told that len function was too heavy and it was better to use count, but I could not remember why, in what context nor who told me so.

Comment: as long as you understand the distinction that you are not asking about an ordinary python list. You are asking about some Django specific type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) returns an integer representing the number of objects in the database matching the QuerySet, it applies only on queryset

it’s much more efficient to handle a count at the database level using `SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*)` that's why you have `count()`

[`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) python built-in function, return the length (the number of items) of an object, it can be applied on queryset as well, but most efficient to use `count()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about python lists then `count()` and `len()` are using for different purposes. `count(el)` will find how many times specific element `el` occurs in the list. While `len()` will give you total count of list's elements.

As for queryset objects just check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) of the docs:

> A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you
>   should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into
>   Python objects and calling len() on the result (unless you need to
>   load the objects into memory anyway, in which case len() will be
>   faster).